# How do I import colors?

Tags: python, colors, import, importerror, livewires

Can anyone explain to me how to import the Python colors? This is for a programming assignment, but I'm stuck here and can't find tutorials online.

I tried `from livewires import games, color`

```
File "/Users/username/Desktop/Programming100/PhysicsLab/PhysicsCsLab.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named livewires
```

I wanted to color shapes such as ellipse, rect, etc., but I don't know how that can be made possible.

Edit: I don't know if this matters or not, but I'm using CALICO.

Comment: Suprisingly, this means that you haven't installed `livewires`.

Comment: I've never heard of livewires. Where can I get this? I don't want to be on random sites due to the ransom bit coin virus.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Thank you. :)

Comment: I don't know if this matters or not, but I'm using CALICO. I know it's Python, but just in case. I still can't get it to work and I installed it.

Answer (score 4):

This just means that you haven't installed the package. Or you *have* installed it, but the python interpreter you're using the run the script does not does not have it installed. This can often happen when `pip` is defined for one python interpreter in particular.

If you have *not* installed it then you can do so using:

```
pip install livewires
```

If that does not help, you're going to go into your interpreter's location, go into `Scripts` and then use `pip install livewires`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the python's package named `livewires`. You can install it via [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) like so: `pip install livewires`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean terminal colors ?
You can try colorma - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama and it works great! 
I am not sure how will you draw shapes though. You can try using curses - http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html